# Create Batch file to Change Subnet Mask only

Tags: batch-file, subnet, netsh

I have about 500 windows servers/systems that have statically set IP's.

I'm getting ready to implement a change to increase network capacity by taking my subnet from a /23 to a /22.

After this change is implemented only the Subnet Mask will change. All other set values will remain the same. I'd really like to not have to change 500 subnet mask addresses. If I can create a batch file, I can deploy that script to all systems on the network. The issue I'm running into is that the several variations of commands I've tried using thus far require that a value be added in for IP address. I've tried the wild card values, but those don't work.

TL;DR?... I need to change only the subnet mask and no other statically set values, and I'd like to find a way to do it using an automated deployment tool that I already have (PDQ Deploy) with a batch file.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us a representative sample of what you've tried, what you expect to happen and describe what actually happened.

Comment: You might try doing a search on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly edit the subnet mask in the registry

Combine a for loop and reg.exe. For a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0:

```
@echo off
for /F %%G IN ('reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services^|find "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"^|find "{"') DO (
reg add "%%G\Parameters\Tcpip" /v SubnetMask /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d 255.255.0.0 /f
)
```

http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/269/ says the subnet mask is REG_BINARY, but I guess it must be outdated because it was REG_MULTI_SZ on my machine (Windows 8.1 x64)